# Using python logging in reusable Django application: "No handlers could be found for logger"

Tags: django, logging

In an open-source Django library I am working on, the `logging` module is used mainly to notice user for potential errors:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_wonderful_function():
    # ... some code ...
    if problem_detected:
        logger.error('Please pay attention, something is wrong...')
```

Since this approach works fine most of the time, if Python 2 users doesn't configure the logging system for my package, they get the error:

> No handlers could be found for logger "library.module"

as soon as the logger is used.

This error does not print out to Python 3 user, since there is a fallback mechanism to output messages to a default `StreamHandler` when no handler can be found for a specific logger (See [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1520)).

My question is:

**Is there a good way to report errors and warnings to user, but to print nothing (and in particular no error) when the user don't want to configure logging?**

Comment: Check Official Django Logging Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works well. I added these 2 functiond in my code:

```
def logger_has_handlers(logger):
    """Since Python 2 doesn't provide Logger.hasHandlers(), we have to
    perform the lookup by ourself."""

    if six.PY3:
        return logger.hasHandlers()
    else:
        c = logger
        rv = False
        while c:
            if c.handlers:
                rv = True
                break
            if not c.propagate:
                break
            else:
                c = c.parent
        return rv


def get_default_logger(name):
    """Get a logger from default logging manager. If no handler
    is associated, add a default NullHandler"""

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if not logger_has_handlers(logger):
        # If logging is not configured in the current project, configure
        # this logger to discard all logs messages. This will prevent
        # the 'No handlers could be found for logger XXX' error on Python 2,
        # and avoid redirecting errors to the default 'lastResort'
        # StreamHandler on Python 3
        logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
    return logger
```

Then, when I need a logger, instead of calling `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, I use `get_default_logger(__name__)`. With this solution, the returned logger always contains at least 1 handler.

If user configured logging by himself, the returned logger contains references to defined handlers. If user didn't configure logging for the package (or configured it without any handler), the `NullHandler` instance associated with the logger ensure no error will be printed when it is used.